# No autocomplete or function information in new install of Eclipse PHP Editor (PDT)

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Recently installed a new version of Eclipse PDT (3.0.2) and auto-complete, function information (ctrl+click), and hovering over for more information didn't work. Same installer worked on another computer, same projects & workspace work on an older version of PDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to recreate the workspace and copy then re-import all the projects.

Someone suggested deleting `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2` this got the hover and crtl+click to work but then eclipse hung every time an auto-complete attempt was made.

Comment: Did you ever try to start eclipse with the `-clear` flag? It has this far fixed any weird issues happening only on one computer. If it happens on multiple computers, it probably is a bug in Eclipse or SWT.

Comment: I had tried doing a clear from the menu once I ran Eclipse but didn't try the -clear flag. Too late now with the workspace remade.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/*` worked for me. This was necessary after upgrading Eclipse.